# Exporting 3D model with texture from blender

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, export

I have imported a high resolution GeoTIFF as a "plane" in Blender. I then make the plane the same size as the image pixel. I then subdivide the surface, add a displacement modifier and this then creates a 3d model of an area of land I am creating a 3d map of.

I then drape my premade map over this by adding it as a material (choosing image as base colour).

I can export nice images, animations etc from this. However, I am struggling to figure out how to export this as a 3d model where I can view the full model with the applied texture, i.e. when I open the STL / OBJ in windows it just shows the plain white model with no image overlain.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures